# Finding the mode of the posterior distribution

Tags: posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, mode

I have the following hierachical bayesian model -
$\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{c},\sigma^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{c},\sigma^2)$
$\mathbf{c}|\mathbf{c}_1,\sigma^2_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{c}|\mathbf{c}_1,\sigma^2_2)$
$\sigma^2 \sim \text{InvGamma}(\alpha, \beta)$.

Here, $\mathbf{x}$ is a data sample. $\alpha$, $\beta$, $c_1$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are fixed known values. $\text{InvGamma}(\cdot)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\cdot)$ are inverse gamma and normal distributions respectively. The goal is to find the mode of the posterior distribution $p(\mathbf{c},\sigma^2|\mathbf{x})$. The method that I tried is Gibbs sampling to generate samples of $(\mathbf{c},\sigma^2)$ and then finding the mode of these samples using mean-shift algorithm. However, the method is computationally demanding and I wanted to know any alternative approaches to obtain the posterior mode efficiently.

Comment: Have you tried deriving the functional form of the posterior and working directly with that?

Comment: You mean taking the gradient of the function with respect to the variables and setting them to 0 ?

Comment: In this case, the functional form of the posterior distribution should be easily recognizable, and finding the posterior mode is a trivial next step.

Comment: You mean it is trivial both for the mean and the variance ?

Comment: Yes.  But even if you don't recognize the functional form, it is still the case that the relevant function is continuous with first and second (and more) derivatives everywhere and unimodal, so many algorithms can find the mode to a high degree of accuracy.

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is no closed form solution to the mode. At the most, I can do gradient descent or Newton's algorithm on the posterior density function to find the optima.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks to me like a standard Normal-Gamma Bayesian model; the posterior mode for $c$ is just the posterior mean and the posterior mode for $\sigma^2$ is the modal value of a $\chi^2$ distribution times the appropriate scale factor.  If you are using R, you can just run it through the `optim` function, no need for a gradient at all with Nelder-Mead as a default.